# Why is it not printing minimum value?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

int maxElement(Node *ptr)
{
    int max;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (max < ptr->data)
        {
            max = ptr->data;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
int minElement(Node *ptr)
{

    int min;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (min > ptr->data)
        {
            min = ptr->data;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
int main()
{

    Node *head = new Node;
    Node *second = new Node;
    Node *third = new Node;
    Node *fourth = new Node;

    head->data = 100;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 200;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 300;
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->data = 400;
    fourth->next = NULL;

    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
    int largestElement = maxElement(head);
    cout << largestElement << endl;

    int smallestElement = minElement(head);
    cout << smallestElement << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Why is my code not printing minimum value? It is printing maximum value but not minimum? I am trying to print minimum and maximum values in a linked list. It's a simple program to print max and min values. I am trying to find a problem but still not getting whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

Your functions `maxElement` and `minElement` are updating the pointer `ptr` only when the maximum/minimum value is updated.

This will result in an infinite loop when a element which is not larger/smaller than previous one exists.

You should update the pointer unconditionally.

Also you should initialize `min` and `max`, or you will use an indeterminate value.

Fixed code:

```cpp
int maxElement(Node *ptr)
{
    int max = ptr == NULL ? 0 : ptr->data; // initialize max before use
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (max < ptr->data)
        {
            max = ptr->data;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next; // update the pointer unconditionally
    }
    return max;
}
int minElement(Node *ptr)
{

    int min = ptr == NULL ? 0 : ptr->data; // initialize min before use
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (min > ptr->data)
        {
            min = ptr->data;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next; // update the pointer unconditionally
    }
    return min;
}
```